# Position absolute child element ignoring parent's margin

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a layout here for my web page and I want to create a certain type of background for one of my sections. Here's how the short markup would look like:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="parentContainer">
        <div class="childContainer">
            Cotent inside the child element.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.parentContainer{
    position:relative;
    margin:9% 0 9% 20%;
    background-color:grey;
}
.childContainer{
    height:50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Here's a fiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/bS2kv/

However, the child element when positioned absolutely as in this case takes position (top:0, left: 0) after taking into account parent's margin. I want the child element to ignore any margin values (which are not fixed as 10/20/40px) and get fitted into the extreme top-left of parent. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4):

Giving the parent element a `position: static` would produce the desired effect

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/bS2kv/4/

Comment: May be late but this did the job perfectly, just remember to set the child as position:absolute; top:0; left:0;

Answer (score -1):

Does using padding instead of margin fit your needs?
Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bS2kv/3/

```
.parentContainer{    
    position:relative;
    padding:9% 0 9% 20%;
    background:gray;    
    height:80px;
}
.childContainer{
    height:50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: yellow;

}
```